# Is there a way to check if a value exists in JSON before actually trying to pull it?

Tags: json, node.js, undefined

So this is my code :

```
                  var result = JSON.parse(res);
              if (result.data.status === 404) {
                client.chatMessage(steamid,"Please check that the order id is correct, Code = ERR:404")
              } else {
              var meta = result.meta_data;
              var tradeurl = meta[0].value;
              var billing = result.billing;
              var name = billing.first_name +" "+ billing.last_name;
              var status = result.status;
              client.chatMessage(steamid,"Name : "+name+"\nTradeUrl : "+ tradeurl +"\n Current Status : " + status)
              }
```

What I am trying to do is first check if the id exists, this is the reply if it doesn't :

```
{ code: 'woocommerce_rest_shop_order_invalid_id',
 message: 'Invalid ID.',
 data: { status: 404 } }
```

As you can see I have added an if condition to check if this value does exist, but the problem is when the order id is correct then a different JSON is returned, which does not contain the `data` field, when in turn crashes the application, so is there a way to check if a field exists in JSON before actually pulling it ?

Comment: *"if a field exists in JSON"* -- [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It doesn't have fields, it is just plain text. You have to decode it into a data structure similar to that used to create the JSON in order to work with it. You can do a blind string search but it won't tell you anything about the level in the data structure where they key you search for is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the order id is correct [...] does not contain the data field

So if `data` is in the response only if an error occured, you could check if `result.data` is undefined or not

```
if (typeof result.data === "undefined") {
  /* ok */
}
else {
  /* error */
}
```

Comment: Hmm... That's actually pretty good, we don't even need to check the code for error 404. Just check if `data` is undefined or not, sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new proposal for ECMAScript called Optional Chaining. Once it's approved, you can do this:

```
var zip = user?.address?.zip
```

And zip will be `undefined` even when `user` is `undefined`, and `address` is non-existent.

Not the working answer, but worth keeping note.

Ref: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining